# How can make Sheet to activate in VBA from a variable? (A cell particularly)

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I am actually quite new to VBA but I am doing some coding to streamline my office work. I understand this would be some amateur level questions to most of you but I tried to google for quite a while and I do not find satisfactory answer.

I have an excel write up that based on the inputted parameters, It should ultimately refer to the correct sheet -> copy the selected cells -> Generate an e-Mail with the body pasting the copied cells along with an attachment

I can do most of the parts, just that I cannot reference the "Correct Sheet" as a variable in my codes. Please shed some lights on for me. Thank you.

Here are most of the codes, the rest are irrelevant and too clumsy to paste all I guess.

```
Sub GenerateEmail()

   Dim olApp As Object
   Dim olMailItm As Object
   Dim iCounter As Integer
   Dim Dest As Variant
   Dim SDest As String
   Dim StrAtt1 As String
   Dim rng As Range



   Set rng = Nothing
   On Error Resume Next
   Set rng = Sheets("test").Range("A1:Q500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   On Error GoTo 0

   If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
   End If

   With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

   Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set olMailItm = olApp.CreateItem(0)

   On Error Resume Next
   With olMailItm
       SDest = ""
       StrAtt1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDF\" & Sheets("Email_Generator").Range("B16")

       .To = Worksheets("Email_Generator").Range("B14")
       .CC = "Myself"
       .BCC = ""
       .Subject = Worksheets("Email_Generator").Range("B18")
       .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
       .attachments.Add StrAtt1
       .Display
   End With

   Set olMailItm = Nothing
   Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Specifically, I would like this code "Sheets("test") as a Cell in Sheet "Test" that is a variable based on the paramters I have inputted in my excel so that this code will reference to the correct worksheet

```
   Set rng = Sheets("test").Range("A1:Q500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

But when I identify the sheet as a named sheet e.g. Sheets("Email1"), it perfectly works, just that it cannot become a variable.

I hope this post is not too long to read because I tried to be as specific as possible. Thank you to all who reads this and tries to help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This function to return the worksheet name selected by the user from an `InputBox`.  If the user cancels or enters an invalid number then the function returns a zero length string.
[image]

```
Sub TestFunction()
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim rng As Range
    SheetName = getSheetNameFromInputBox
    If Len(SheetName) = 0 Then
       MsgBox Prompt:="Try Again", Title:="Invalid Sheet"
       Exit Sub
    End If
    Set rng = Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1:Q500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    MsgBox rng.Address(External:=True)
End Sub

Function getSheetNameFromInputBox() As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Prompt As String
    Dim result

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name = "Sheet3" Then
            Prompt = Prompt & ws.Index & ") " & ws.Name & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next

    result = InputBox(Prompt:=Prompt, Title:="Enter the Worksheet number", Default:=1)
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsNumeric(result) Then getSheetNameFromInputBox = Worksheets(CInt(result)).Name
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Hello Thomas, thank you for your reply, in fact, the referenced sheet will be based on different currency pairs, which each pair will have an own sheet itself, is it possible to reference it to a cell instead of a box to input so that the users won't have to type the lengthy sheet names, i am most likely gonna have 10+ sheets, which it is not possible to name those sheets as 1 2 3 4 5 etc. 

That particular cell is actually automatically generated from what parameters I have entered in the generator worksheet.

Again thank you for your reply.

Comment: @keiar The function uses the worksheet's index as a reference but also list the worksheets name.  Paste the function in a code module and press F5 to see what I mean.  Alternatively, you could use a cell with validation list that you could reference.

Comment: Thomas: Thanks, I tried to paste your codes in but I keep getting errors when I try to run it, I suppose I have pasted it on a wrong place, do you mind to show me where I should add them in? Do I have to Dim the "Sheetname" too? I am sure I have missed out something very obvious.

Comment: @keiar Sorry about that.  I forgot that  I had to typecast the results.  I updated my answer to include a test.

Comment: Thanks mate, I know my vba knowledge is very bad, please do not be sorry, I should have noticed that myself, I will give a try to your updated code later, thank you for your help so far.

Comment: You should watch [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

Comment: Thomas: Yes I agree I should take a look at that video, will do that at home later.

Comment: I included an if statement inside the function as an example.  You could use if ws.index > 4 then